# Como generar un pst con python o c#

Tags: python, c#, imap

Actualmente tengo un script que me genera respaldo de los correos electronicos de una cuenta de email atravez de una conexion imap. Este script baja todos los correos en forma de eml, ademas crea sub carpetas y tambien guarda los correos en sus respectivas sub carpeta. Estoy buscando alguna manera de generar el pst apartir de lo descargado,  e intentado manipular outlook con win32 pero he muerto en el inteneto, alguien conoce algun metodo por medio de biblioteca o aprovechamiento de algun programa para lograr esto.

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import os
import re

# Configuración de la cuenta de correo
email_address = 'email@mail.com'
password = 'pass'
server = 'server.serveremail.com'

# Conexión al servidor IMAP de Rackspace
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)

# Inicio de sesión
mail.login(email_address, password)

# Obtiene una lista de todas las carpetas
status, folders = mail.list()

# Carpeta para almacenar los archivos de respaldo
backup_root_folder = 'backup_emails'
backup_folder = ''
os.makedirs(backup_root_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Recorre todas las carpetas y respalda los mensajes de cada una
for folder_info in folders:
    print(folder_info)
    # Decodifica la información de la carpeta
    folder_info_decoded = str(folder_info)
    folder_name_regex = re.compile(r'\".\" \"?INBOX(\.([^\"]+))?(\"|\')?')
    # Extrae el nombre de la carpeta usando expresiones regulares
    match = folder_name_regex.search(folder_info_decoded)
    if match:
        folder_name = match.group(2) if match.group(2) else "INBOX"
        # Verifica si el nombre de la carpeta contiene caracteres especiales
        if re.search(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', folder_name):
            print(f"La carpeta '{folder_name}' contiene caracteres especiales y será omitida.")
            continue
        print("************* SIPASO***** " + folder_name)

        # Crea la carpeta de respaldo correspondiente
        if folder_name != "INBOX":
            folder_name =  folder_name.replace(".", os.path.sep)
            folder_name = folder_name.replace("'", "")
            backup_folder = os.path.join(backup_root_folder, folder_name)
            print(backup_folder)
            os.makedirs(backup_folder, exist_ok=True)

        # Selecciona la carpeta actual
        try:
            status, _ = mail.select(folder_name)
            if status != 'OK':
                print(f"No se pudo seleccionar la carpeta {folder_name}. Estado: {status}")
                continue
            else:
                print(status+" si seleccionamos----------------****>>>"+folder_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error al seleccionar la carpeta {folder_name}: {e}")
            continue
        # Busca todos los mensajes en la carpeta actual
        try:
            status, messages = mail.uid('search', None, 'ALL')
            if status != 'OK':
                print(f"No se pudo buscar mensajes en la carpeta {folder_name}. Estado: {status}")
                continue
            else:
                print('si se obtuvieron los mensajes')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error al buscar mensajes en la carpeta {folder_name}: {e}")
            continue
        print('*********************************************************************************')
        # Descarga cada mensaje y guarda como archivos .eml en la carpeta de respaldo
        for msg_id in messages[0].split():
            _, msg_data = mail.uid('fetch', msg_id, '(RFC822)')
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_data[0][1])

            # Decodifica el asunto del mensaje para usarlo como nombre de archivo
            if msg.get('Subject'):
                subject, encoding = decode_header(msg.get('Subject'))[0]
                if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                    subject = subject.decode(encoding or 'utf-8')
            else:
                subject = 'Sin asunto'
            # Reemplaza los caracteres no permitidos en el nombre del archivo
            cleaned_subject = re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', '', subject)

            # Elimina caracteres específicos no permitidos
            invalid_chars = ['', '\uf0fc', '\t']
            for char in invalid_chars:
                cleaned_subject = cleaned_subject.replace(char, '')
            backup_file_path = ''
            folder_name =  folder_name.replace(".", os.path.sep)
            folder_name = folder_name.replace("'", "")
            # Guarda el mensaje en un archivo .eml en la carpeta de respaldo
            if folder_name != "INBOX":
                backup_folder = os.path.join(backup_root_folder, folder_name)
                backup_file_path = os.path.join(backup_folder, f'{cleaned_subject}.eml')
            else:
                backup_file_path = os.path.join(backup_root_folder, f'{cleaned_subject}.eml')
            # Imprime el nombre de archivo antes de intentar guardarlo
            print("Guardando mensaje como:", backup_file_path)

            # Abre el archivo con el argumento 'wb' configurado para manejar todos los caracteres
            
            with open(backup_file_path, 'wb') as backup_file:
                backup_file.write(msg_data[0][1])
    else:

        print(f"No se pudo obtener el nombre de la carpeta:")
# Cierra la conexión
mail.logout()

print("Backup completado. Mensajes guardados en las carpetas de respaldo.")
```

Esto funciona en windows

El siguiente scrip con el que no tuve mucho exito fue para crear el pst

```
import os
import win32com.client

def create_pst_from_eml(source_folder, pst_file_path):
    Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    if not os.path.exists(pst_file_path):
        Outlook.AddStore(pst_file_path)
    try:
        PSTFolderObj = find_pst_folder(Outlook, pst_file_path)
        for root, _, files in os.walk(source_folder):
            for file_name in files:
                if file_name.endswith('.eml'):
                    eml_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                    with open(eml_file_path, 'rb') as eml_file:
                        eml_data = eml_file.read()
                        msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parsebytes(eml_data)
                        PSTFolderObj.Items.Add(msg)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    finally:
        Outlook.RemoveStore(PSTFolderObj)

def find_pst_folder(OutlookObj, pst_filepath):
    for Store in OutlookObj.Stores:
        if Store.IsDataFileStore and Store.FilePath == pst_filepath:
            return Store.GetRootFolder()
    return None

def enumerate_folders(FolderObj):
    for ChildFolder in FolderObj.Folders:
        enumerate_folders(ChildFolder)
    iterate_messages(FolderObj)

def iterate_messages(FolderObj):
    for item in FolderObj.Items:
        print("***************************************")
        print(item.SenderName)
        print(item.SenderEmailAddress)
        print(item.SentOn)
        print(item.To)
        print(item.CC)
        print(item.BCC)
        print(item.Subject)

        count_attachments = item.Attachments.Count
        if count_attachments > 0:
            for att in range(count_attachments):
                print(item.Attachments.Item(att + 1).Filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_folder = r"C:\Users\\Desktop\respaldo\backup_emails"
    pst_file_path = r"C:\Users\\Desktop\respaldo\backup_emails.pst"
    create_pst_from_eml(source_folder, pst_file_path)
```

si alguien tiene alguna forma de hacer esto estoy abierto a sugerencias ya sea en python, c# u otro lenguaje. Habia pensado en readpst pero estoy en windows.

Comment: Probaste con [Aspose.Email-for-Python-via-NET/](https://pypi.org/project/Aspose.Email-for-Python-via-NET/)?

Comment: no, he leido poco de asponse, eso es opennsource, o hay que pagar definitivamente?

Answer (score 0):

**Nota**: No soy usuario de Outlook, ni se mucho sobre la api de Windows, como para poder solucionar el error planteado, por lo que esta respuesta está enfocada a la busqueda de una forma independiente de escribir un pst.

---

##### Hablando de Módulos

Lo unico que encontré es [Aspose.Email-for-Python-via-NET/](https://pypi.org/project/Aspose.Email-for-Python-via-NET/), pero,
dado que la pagina oficial ofrece una trial y a la vez un módulo en pip (que si o si es gratis),
tengo la hipotesis (y por [lo que leí](https://about.aspose.com/es/)) de que el módulo es gratuito, pero el uso de la api a la que podría comunicarse es paga.

Alternativas a aspose, no encontré nada a la fecha de esta respuesta...

##### Escribiendo un módulo por tu cuenta.

Por lo que, para escribir un pst sin usar la api de Windows, deberás crear tu propio módulo.

Para aprender a escribirlo, te recomiendo seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. El .pst es un [archivo binario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_binario). Esto significa, que se requiere conocer al menos como manejar datos en forma de [bytes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). El modulo [struct](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/struct.html)(que ya viene incluido con Python) es de mucha ayuda para este proposito.
2. Interpreta la documentación que habla del formato del archivo. Encontré [algo en ingles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-pst/141923d5-15ab-4ef1-a524-6dce75aae546#published-version), que tengo entendido es documentación oficial.
3. Así haría yo el módulo: Para el lado de Python, crea clases que representen las distintas estructuras que estarían en el archivo binario. Cuando requieras escribirlo en un archivo, podés crear un método en todas tus clases llamado write, que convierta el objeto en bytes y lo vaya escribiendo en el archivo.

Lamentablemente, soy muy malo leyendo documentación sobre archivos binarios, y no ayuda que el archivo tenga una estructura compleja, por lo que no puedo darte un ejemplo de como lograr esto. Pero espero que te vaya bien y encuentres una solución alternativa o entiendas como aplicar esta.